# trying to installing magento in xampp in localhost

Tags: magento, xampp

trying to installing magento in xampp in localhost

[image: magento screen]

but in this screen when I click continue it displaying same page with no error.
my magento version is - 1.8.0
and xampp version is - 1.7.7

Comment: check the option 'Skip base url' and then continue ...

Comment: thanks but,
It's also not worked.

Comment: well, change the url to 'http://127.0.0.1/magento' and then continue

Comment: that's also not worked

Comment: check whether the xampp is running both apache and mysql..

Comment: and is the database with name "magentotest" is present? (sorry to ask this silly questions, because you haven't provided them)

Comment: @JayDeep Nimavat follow the Mr_Green's last comment "check whether the xampp is running both apache and mysql", and database availability

Comment: ya I already created database name magentotest and my xampp and apache both are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your browser and usw `http://127.0.0.1/magento/` instead of `http://localhost/magento/` and start the installation process again,  it will work.

Comment: make sure cookie is not disabled in your browswer and check your log file

Comment: Make sure you have enabled all of the following ,curl is disabled by default in xampp and  try again 

Required extensions:
PDO_MySQL
simplexml
mcrypt
hash
GD
DOM
icony
curl
SOAP (if Webservices API is to be used)
Safe_mode off
Memory_limit no less than 256Mb (preferably 512)

Comment: now its worked but give another error
Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Open `c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`  Once opened, look for this line:

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```

   and remove the # at the beginning of the line, so it should look like this:

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```
2. Go to the `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` file Now find this line within php.ini:

   ```
   ;extension=php_curl.dll
   ```

   and remove the semicolon (;) so that the line will look like this:

   ```
   extension=php_curl.dll
   ```
3. During the installation, Magento will require a few minutes to complete one of its tasks. Your XAMPP installation is likely to allow less time than this and as a result, will corrupt the Magento installation. The solution for this problem is to increase the timeout threshold in the php.ini file.

   You can do this by locating the following string in php.ini:

   ```
   max_execution_time = 30
   ```

   and increasing the 30 to 1600 so that it looks like this:

   ```
   max_execution_time = 1600
   ```

   After that, save php.ini and close out the file.

   Note: Use bitnami to download magento.  It's working fine with xamp.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this tutorial](http://tutorialmagento.com/how-to-install-magento-on-xampp-localhost) and successfully installed Magento on Localhost Xampp webserver. I think it's because you didn't turn on these extensions in php.in:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
```

You should install the extensions above first.
Also, remember to clear cache of your browser. If it's not working you may try to start from scratch with the tutorial I used.
Hope this helps